# How to check whether postscript file generation completed or not?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, acrobat, postscript

In my code i have to generate postscript file using a word word document and finally it converts to PDF document using the postscript file(Using Acrobat Distiller).

I have one issue here while it converts word document to postscript file it is taking time to generate postscript file. Issue is with out completing the generated of the postscript file my code moves to next statement to generated PDF file using postscript file as Input parameter.
Here i want to put a check whether a postscript file generation completed and then it should move to the next statement to generated PDF.

#### Code to Convert Word to PostScript file

```
public Word.Application objWordApp = null; 
public Word.Document objWordDoc = null;

object objMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                if (Convert.ToString(objWordApp.ActivePrinter) != AdobePDF)
                {
                    SetDefaultPrinter(AdobePDF);
                }
                objWordDoc.PrintOut(ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, objWordOutputPath, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing);
```

#### Code Which converts Postscript file to PDF

```
private PdfDistiller objPDFMaker;
public void ConvertToPDF(string psfile, string outputName)
{
  objPDFMaker.FileToPDF(psfile, outputName, "");
}
```

How can i check whether Postscript file generation Completed ?

Comment: Hi All, Could you please help me out..

Comment: Is it possible to call `PrintOut()` in a blocking manner? Maybe one of those arguments can be used to set a mode, or pass a call-back function for notification.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this (when you don't have a completion event or similar mutex) is to sit in a loop and examine the file size, if it doesn't change for a period of time (up to you to decide how long) then its stable and presumably finished.

This isn't a question relevant to PostScript though.

Why do you not use the PDFMaker macros supplied with Acrobat to have Word create a PDF file directly instead of going to PostScript first ?

Comment: I tried using PDFMaker which converts word to PDF directly but we are not getting the exact pdf which contains images and text on it. To avoid this issue we are using some fonts loaded in Acrobat Distiller and we are converting word to .ps and then .ps to PDF.

Comment: While converting word to postscript file its taking time. Here i need to put a check whether that postscript file generation completed. Once it is completed the ps file it should convert to pdf using acrobat distiller.